# Prove that $\text{dom }\bigcup\mathfrak{A}=\bigcup\{\text{dom }R|R\in\mathfrak{A}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to solve the following question:

> Show that for any set $\mathfrak{A}$: $$\text{dom }\bigcup\mathfrak{A}=\bigcup\{\text{dom }R|R\in\mathfrak{A}\}$$

I don't understand how. Take $\mathfrak{A}=\{\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\},\{\{c\},\{e,f\}\},\{\{g\},\{c,d\}\}\}$.

Then $\text{dom }\mathfrak{A}=\{a,c\}$. However, $\bigcup\{\text{dom }R|R\in\mathfrak{A}\}=\{a\}$. How I worked that out is I took each element of $\mathfrak{A}$, and saw if it was f the form $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. If it was, then $x\in\text{dom }R$. If not, then move on to the next element.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that thinking about ordered pairs in the Kuratowski definition obfuscates the meaning, and it makes it somewhat harder to understand this question.

Instead of writing $\{\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\ldots$, write $\{R,S\}$ and $R=\{\langle a,b\rangle\}$ and $S=\{\langle a,c\rangle,\langle b,d\rangle\}$.

Then $\{\operatorname{dom} R\mid R\in\frak A\}$ is the set $\{a,b\}$ and $\operatorname{dom}\bigcup\frak A$ is the domain of the relation $\{\langle a,b\rangle,\langle a,c\rangle,\langle b,d\rangle\}$ which happens to be exactly $\{a,b\}$.

Work with the definition of $\operatorname{dom}$, and use $\langle a,b\rangle$ notation -- the less braces, the easier it is for humans to parse the statement.

Comment: How is the set I wrote down the same as $\{\langle a,b\rangle, \langle a,c\rangle, \langle b,d\rangle\}$?

Comment: It's not. It's a simpler example, and through this example I hoped to help you see clearly into the question.